# What does -1.#IND mean (double stream output)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, stream, double

I could neither find it via google, search here or on Microsofts helppages...

After some extensive calculations, sometimes, when outputting my doubles via `std::cout` i prints as result on console:

**-1.#IND**

There are no modifcations(like precision etc) to the cout-stream. I assume the program wants to tell me about some sort of error, but I can't figure it out :/
It doesn't happen that often but with a low frequency (it is a genetical algorithm, so i have an output after every generation, and in about every 5th to 10th generation this seems to happen...)

For information, I'm using Visual Studio Pro 2013.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: This stands for INDeterminate also known as NaN (Not A Number) and is the result of an illegal operation like a division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Windows displays NaN as -1.#IND. NaN is a result of a mathematical operation that does not make sense. For example, 0.0 / 0.0, or sqrt(-1.0) will return NaN. I can't really help further without more details about the underlying operation. Hopefully this is enough to point you in the right direction, though.